# How to clean up after CREATE DIALOG CONVERSATION on disconnect?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

---Edited to include more and better details---

In SQL Server, you can initialize a conversation on a queue:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187377.aspx

Multiple processes will all initialize conversations, store the @dialog_handle in table [dbo].[ActiveConversations], and then WAITFOR a message to arrive (from a trigger on a table).

Here's the gist of what the code is doing (leaving out some irrelevant
complications and error checking and such):

Starting the conversation via .NET SqlCommand:

```
DECLARE @LoginTime datetime;
DECLARE @handle uniqueidentifier;
SELECT TOP 1 @LoginTime = login_time FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = @@SPID;
BEGIN DIALOG @handle
   FROM SERVICE [myService]
   TO SERVICE 'myService'
   ON CONTRACT myContract
   WITH ENCRYPTION=OFF;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ActiveConversations]
(
   ConversationHandle,
   SysProcessID,
   SysProcessLoginTime
)
VALUES
(
   @handle,
   @@SPID,
   @LoginTime
)
```

Ending the conversation via .NET SqlCommand:

```
DECLARE @handle uniqueidentifier;
SELECT TOP 1 @handle = ConversationHandle
   FROM [dbo].[ActiveConversations] AS conv
   INNER JOIN sys.sysprocesses as sysp
      ON conv.SysProcessLoginTime = sysp.login_time;

DELETE FROM [dbo].[ActiveConversations] WHERE ConversationHandle = @handle;
END CONVERSATION @handle;
```

Sending messages:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[myTableChanged] ON [dbo].[myTable] AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @handle uniqueidentifier;
   DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
   FOR
   SELECT ConversationHandle FROM [dbo].[ActiveConversations];

   OPEN curs
   FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @handle;
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
         SEND ON CONVERSATION @handle
            MESSAGE TYPE [myType] ( '' );
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
      END CATCH
      FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @ConversationHandle;
   END
   CLOSE curs;
   DEALLOCATE curs;
END
```

Waiting for messages:

```
DECLARE @handle uniqueidentifier;
SELECT @handle = [ConversationHandle]
    FROM [dbo].ActiveConversations] AS conv
    INNER JOIN sys.sysprocesses AS sysp
    ON sysp.spid = conv.SysProcessID
    AND sysp.login_time = conv.SysProcessLoginTime
    AND sysp.spid = @@SPID;

WAITFOR (RECEIVE * FROM [dbo].[myQueue] WHERE conversation_handle = @handle);
```

When each process exits, it is responsible for calling END CONVERSATION.  However, if a process were to die an untimely death, it will never get a chance to call END CONVERSATION, and the conversation will sit out there forever.  Or will it?

Will the conversation be cleaned up automatically, or how do you make sure dead conversations don't accumulate?

What's the best practice in this scenario?  Is it to set a specific timeout and then re-initialize the conversation periodically?  If the conversation ends unexpectedly, is there a way to find out so it can be deleted from the [dbo].[ActiveConversations] table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box mechanism to say "has the far side service received messages within some time span?". That said, we can use conversation timers to accomplish it. The gist of it is that the target service, once it gets signal that a new conversation is starting, begins a conversation timer and records that conversation's handle in a table (along with a time stamp). When that timer expires, the activation procedure checks the table to see when the last heartbeat message from the initiator service was processed. If it's outside of a predetermined tolerance, the conversation is ended. In parallel, the initiator service sends heartbeat messages on a cadence letting the target service know that it's still alive.

Here's the setup code:

```
use master;
go
if exists (select 1 from sys.databases where name = 'TimerInitiator')
begin
    alter database [TimerInitiator] set offline with rollback immediate;
    alter database [TimerInitiator] set online;
    drop database [TimerInitiator];
end

if exists (select 1 from sys.databases where name = 'TimerTarget')
begin
    alter database [TimerTarget] set offline with rollback immediate;
    alter database [TimerTarget] set online;
    drop database [TimerTarget];
end

create database [TimerInitiator];
create database [TimerTarget];
revert;
go

use [TimerInitiator];
create master key encryption by password = 'f00bar!23';
create user [BrokerUser] without login;
CREATE CERTIFICATE [BrokerCert] AUTHORIZATION [BrokerUser] FROM BINARY = 0x308201E33082014CA00302010202101A83EEBC1E132A9149AC7D6D5AA1423F300D06092A864886F70D0101050500302F312D302B06035504031324436572746966696361746520666F722062726F6B657220636F6D6D756E69636174696F6E3020170D3137303132323034303430315A180F32303939303130313030303030305A302F312D302B06035504031324436572746966696361746520666F722062726F6B657220636F6D6D756E69636174696F6E30819F300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818D0030818902818100BC4C750343E36206C5A8D672C06D5A204DE499F1CF94A5D678F12DA2F9834877C901AEFE11CA64F9FEA46E31E65FA66FFD80DA139386F3F834C65114025563A9BBD85BDAAFAA694C1D2A36060B380BBD658DD2D93643303F2018F605AAB31840659EF0B5034766FF00F69EF0C1FF9A035686EC81C1E9995C599833ACCEF1BA230203010001300D06092A864886F70D01010505000381810081163FBED4A8B85429C6B6AC7D2123671F751EB72A468CCFBF2C593A8E2A7F51F59584D4EE7ECD247BD73D7A809007C0A8BE23E18A90AC927C124632578F971CD177269EF6752891DDFAB43DC0F1A24D509116EE578BAAC553B81376A69F386B6401AADF1C9D0D2121070B216C864C31B12D8B02081C35D70A8B7DFBD8904DF5 WITH PRIVATE KEY (BINARY = 0x1EF1B5B000000000010000000100000010000000540200005795E582353CC30C984D89654C0B65170702000000A40000B92EB9B271982F1DA38DCC06FC333E60512569DD94A1B661FAAC382E73665869FF9F2995A58812E64163354FA81C957EBF29DA8F20699C59AA16268401C0679FEEF639AB9C38E0C4E4E605F8DCDFB6CC5CB011F7113170EE6CE49623DE061D6FB82F8ABE92284E9D1FA481FCD150AA0B356FCFC86593EF3D7DDC03D7893462A9C1AA628970C04FE4ECB92E8E5234600A059D4213CE51369E0C0D8B2676F9F4E7FC08A6043991A21716DBB8C05B62E78A36571361C646C3D3BEE252A816CDDF6184E4954CE8EF65A584CDC1C45E9D17CE5B2ABB4CCCEF86A4F943DA26792E5BFCEA7E379BE98E799DCBF06C4235F2B685772842F181383FC1DC420660B17F5A9FD8460C50054AC50CF1BB57C6DD36D6CA40AC596E0AA492254B3E7D52A9F2079FBEB7CA1B6659B9923CBA72FA7DAFA67B83726C623AE4568F83EB748CAB6D7A87DCFD964E90A92C14649B99CAEE56DAEC3139DF1B33B1683D1E67357C9A6B563686A16842C2BBE0CCA0C41A6565FB90505F83F1F1D6B28B786DD7FEDDE7DEBC5A3A7BC3407DC77DBC49DB27135F4E09BA23CCFAA7C551C020B06AF4F585A5AD72A19DF35D9B04F0956B9ADFFFF1BE5897026CEC6D1B9582E2559F9354D09844B4058E656780579CF6FBE342522B40126D095749AAFAAAD4C3D53B8E1C469CF4EB18150F3A7D2ED6E308BAA71375D3657688AC0DBD3709E4412B8625DB53516292CCBE5E324DD6139C9D6F6522CD5FCC1229284B2B78D1D5246461BA930428065E9FC6738EF885D9A3EED1D2CAEC0368CA6D09D0DF2DB9C9042C29076087EF043DD085AE12EC561AABADB92B5A, DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'f00bar!23')
create message type [Request] validation = none;
create message type [Response] validation = none;
create message type [Heartbeat] validation = none;
create contract [ConversationContract] (
    [Request] sent by initiator,
    [Response] sent by target,
    [Heartbeat] sent by initiator
);
create queue [InitiatorQueue] ;
create service [InitiatorService] 
    authorization [BrokerUser] 
    on queue [InitiatorQueue]
    ( [ConversationContract] );

create remote service binding [TimerRSB]
    authorization [BrokerUser]
    to service 'TargetService'
    with user = [BrokerUser];

declare @broker_instance uniqueidentifier;
select @broker_instance = service_broker_guid
from sys.databases
where name = 'TimerTarget';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = concat(
'create route [TimerTargetRoute]
with service_name = ''TargetService'',
    broker_instance = ''', @broker_instance,
    ''', address = ''LOCAL''');
exec(@sql)
go

go
create procedure [InitiatorActivation]
as
begin
    declare @ch uniqueidentifier, @message_type sysname;

    while(1=1)
    begin
        waitfor (
            receive top(1) @ch = conversation_handle,
                @message_type = message_type_name
            from [dbo].[InitiatorQueue]
        ), timeout 1000;

        if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
            break;

        --if (@message_type = 'Response')
        --begin
        --  -- do something to process the message
        --end
        --else 
        if (@message_type = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
        begin
            end conversation @ch
        end
    end
end
go
alter queue [dbo].[InitiatorQueue] with activation (
    procedure_name = [dbo].[InitiatorActivation], 
    max_queue_readers = 5, 
    status = on,
    execute as owner
);
go

create procedure [dbo].[SendHeartbeat] (
    @ch uniqueidentifier
)
as
begin
    send on conversation (@ch)
        message type [Heartbeat];
end
go

use [TimerTarget];
create master key encryption by password = 'f00bar!23';
create user [BrokerUser] without login;
CREATE CERTIFICATE [BrokerCert] AUTHORIZATION [BrokerUser] FROM BINARY = 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f00bar!23')
create message type [Request] validation = none;
create message type [Response] validation = none;
create message type [Heartbeat] validation = empty;
create contract [ConversationContract] (
    [Request] sent by initiator,
    [Response] sent by target,
    [Heartbeat] sent by initiator
);
create queue [TargetQueue];
create service [TargetService] 
    authorization [BrokerUser] 
    on queue [TargetQueue]
    ( [ConversationContract] );

create remote service binding [TimerRSB]
    authorization [BrokerUser]
    to service 'InitiatorService'
    with user = [BrokerUser];


declare @broker_instance uniqueidentifier;
select @broker_instance = service_broker_guid
from sys.databases
where name = 'TimerInitiator';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = concat(
'create route [TimerInitiatorRoute]
with service_name = ''InitiatorService'',
    broker_instance = ''', @broker_instance,
    ''', address = ''LOCAL''');
exec(@sql);
go
create table [dbo].[OpenConversations] (
    conversation_handle uniqueidentifier not null,
        constraint [PK_OpenConversations] primary key clustered (conversation_handle),
    heartbeat_ts datetime2(3) not null
);
go
create procedure [dbo].[TargetActivation]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @message_type sysname,
        @ch uniqueidentifier,
        @heartbeat_ts datetime2(3);
    while(1=1)
    begin
        waitfor(
            receive top(1) @message_type = message_type_name,
                @ch = conversation_handle
            from [dbo].[TargetQueue]
        ), timeout 1000;

        if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
            break;
        if @message_type = 'Request'
        begin
            insert into [dbo].[OpenConversations] 
                (conversation_handle, heartbeat_ts)
            values
                (@ch, SYSUTCDATETIME());
            begin conversation timer (@ch) timeout = 30; -- 30 seconds
        end
        else if (@message_type = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer')
        begin
            set @heartbeat_ts = (
                select [heartbeat_ts] 
                from [dbo].[OpenConversations] 
                where [conversation_handle] = @ch
            );

            if (datediff(second, @heartbeat_ts, SYSUTCDATETIME()) > 5*60) -- 5 minute time out
            begin
                end conversation @ch;
                delete [dbo].[OpenConversations]
                where [conversation_handle] = @ch;
            end
            else
            begin
                begin conversation timer (@ch) timeout = 30;
            end
        end
        else if (@message_type = 'Heartbeat')
        begin
            update [dbo].[OpenConversations]
            set [heartbeat_ts] = SYSUTCDATETIME()
            where [conversation_handle] = @ch;
        end
    end
end
go
alter queue [dbo].[TargetQueue] with activation (
    procedure_name = [dbo].[TargetActivation], 
    max_queue_readers = 5, 
    status = on,
    execute as owner
);
go
```

Most of this is service broker plumbing. The "interesting" part is in the activation procedure `InitiatorActivation`. That's that's where the tracking of timers and whether a given conversation has expired or not is tracked.

Here's some code to exercise the setup:

```
use [TimerInitiator]
go
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#conversations') is not null
    drop table #conversations;
create table #conversations (conversation_handle uniqueidentifier not null);

declare @ch uniqueidentifier, @i tinyint = 0;

-- start 5 conversations
while(@i < 5)
begin
    begin dialog @ch
        from service [InitiatorService]
        to service 'TargetService'
        on contract [ConversationContract];

    send on conversation (@ch)
        message type [Request]
        ('<Request />');

    insert into #conversations ([conversation_handle])
    values (@ch);

    set @i += 1;
end

go

declare @ch uniqueidentifier = (select top(1) [conversation_handle] from #conversations)
while (1=1)
begin
    exec [TimerInitiator].[dbo].[SendHeartbeat] @ch = @ch;
    waitfor delay '0:00:30';
end
```

All that's happening here is that five conversations are started and one is arbitrarily chosen to send periodic heartbeats. In another window, you can run one or all of the following to track how things are going:

```
select 'T', conversation_handle, message_type_name
from [TimerTarget].[dbo].[TargetQueue]
union all 
select 'I', conversation_handle, message_type_name
from [TimerInitiator].[dbo].[InitiatorQueue];

select 'T', conversation_handle, state_desc
from TimerInitiator.sys.conversation_endpoints
union all
select 'I', conversation_handle, state_desc
from TimerTarget.sys.conversation_endpoints;

select *
from [TimerTarget].[dbo].[OpenConversations];
```

In your actual setup, it will be your application sending heartbeats. Which it should do regardless of whether it's processing messages or not (i.e. if you hit a period where no messages are sent by the target, your application still needs to send heartbeats). Other than that, this should work with minimal tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought to use a conversation timer, while it may have worked, is probably overkill. Instead, it's probably easier to set a lifetime on the conversation when you send it. When that lifetime expires, the conversation automatically errors out which places an error message in both the initiator and target queue for that conversation. Here's a POC. As I alluded to in my comment below, a lot of this is plumbing code. Here goes:

```
use master;
go
if exists (select 1 from sys.databases where name = 'TimerInitiator')
begin
    alter database [TimerInitiator] set offline with rollback immediate;
    alter database [TimerInitiator] set online;
    drop database [TimerInitiator];
end

if exists (select 1 from sys.databases where name = 'TimerTarget')
begin
    alter database [TimerTarget] set offline with rollback immediate;
    alter database [TimerTarget] set online;
    drop database [TimerTarget];
end

--execute as login = 'sa';
create database [TimerInitiator];
create database [TimerTarget];
revert;
go

use [TimerInitiator];
create master key encryption by password = 'f00bar!23';
create user [BrokerUser] without login;
CREATE CERTIFICATE [BrokerCert] AUTHORIZATION [BrokerUser] FROM BINARY = 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f00bar!23')
create message type [Request] validation = none;
create message type [Response] validation = none;
create contract [ConversationContract] (
    [Request] sent by initiator,
    [Response] sent by target
);
create queue [InitiatorQueue] ;
create service [InitiatorService] 
    authorization [BrokerUser] 
    on queue [InitiatorQueue]
    ( [ConversationContract] );

create remote service binding [TimerRSB]
    authorization [BrokerUser]
    to service 'TargetService'
    with user = [BrokerUser];

declare @broker_instance uniqueidentifier;
select @broker_instance = service_broker_guid
from sys.databases
where name = 'TimerTarget';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = concat(
'create route [TimerTargetRoute]
with service_name = ''TargetService'',
    broker_instance = ''', @broker_instance,
    ''', address = ''LOCAL''');
exec(@sql)
go

create table [dbo].[ConversationHistory] (
    conversation_handle uniqueidentifier,
    status varchar(100) null
);
go
create procedure [InitiatorActivation]
as
begin
    declare @ch uniqueidentifier, @message_type sysname;

    while(1=1)
    begin
        waitfor (
            receive top(1) @ch = conversation_handle,
                @message_type = message_type_name
            from [dbo].[InitiatorQueue]
        ), timeout 10000;

        if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
            break;

        if (@message_type = 'Response')
        begin
            update [dbo].[ConversationHistory]
            set status = 'Received response'
            where conversation_handle = @ch;
        end
        else
        begin
            update [dbo].[ConversationHistory]
            set status = 'Conversation timed out'
            where conversation_handle = @ch;
        end
        end conversation @ch
    end
end
go
alter queue [dbo].[InitiatorQueue] with activation (
    procedure_name = [dbo].[InitiatorActivation], 
    max_queue_readers = 5, 
    status = on,
    execute as owner
);

use [TimerTarget];
create master key encryption by password = 'f00bar!23';
create user [BrokerUser] without login;
CREATE CERTIFICATE [BrokerCert] AUTHORIZATION [BrokerUser] FROM BINARY = 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f00bar!23')
create message type [Request] validation = none;
create message type [Response] validation = none;
create contract [ConversationContract] (
    [Request] sent by initiator,
    [Response] sent by target
);
create queue [TargetQueue];
create service [TargetService] 
    authorization [BrokerUser] 
    on queue [TargetQueue]
    ( [ConversationContract] );

create remote service binding [TimerRSB]
    authorization [BrokerUser]
    to service 'InitiatorService'
    with user = [BrokerUser];


declare @broker_instance uniqueidentifier;
select @broker_instance = service_broker_guid
from sys.databases
where name = 'TimerInitiator';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = concat(
'create route [TimerInitiatorRoute]
with service_name = ''InitiatorService'',
    broker_instance = ''', @broker_instance,
    ''', address = ''LOCAL''');
exec(@sql);
go
create procedure [dbo].[TargetActivation]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @message_type sysname,
        @ch uniqueidentifier;
    while(1=1)
    begin
        waitfor(
            receive top(1) @message_type = message_type_name,
                @ch = conversation_handle
            from [dbo].[TargetQueue]
        ), timeout 10000;

        if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
            break;
        if @message_type = 'Request'
        begin
            if (datepart(millisecond, getdate()) < 500)
            begin
                -- simulate a long-running process
                waitfor delay '0:0:11';
            end
            begin try
                send on conversation (@ch)
                    message type [Response]
                    ('<Response />');
            end try
            begin catch
                if ERROR_NUMBER() = 8429 --tried to send on an errored conversation
                begin
                    continue;
                end
            end catch
        end
        end conversation @ch;
    end
end
go
alter queue [dbo].[TargetQueue] with activation (
    procedure_name = [dbo].[TargetActivation], 
    max_queue_readers = 5, 
    status = on,
    execute as owner
);
go
use [TimerInitiator];

declare @ch uniqueidentifier, @i int = 0;
set nocount on;

while(@i < 100)
begin
--declare @ch uniqueidentifier;
    begin dialog conversation @ch
        from service [InitiatorService]
        to service 'TargetService'
        on contract [ConversationContract]
        with lifetime = 60;

    send on conversation (@ch)
        message type [Request]
        ('<request />');

    insert into dbo.ConversationHistory (conversation_handle)
    values (@ch);

    set @i += 1;
end

waitfor delay '00:01:05';
select status, count(*)
from dbo.ConversationHistory
group by status;
```

Talking through the semantics of the above, I've designed a message protocol that sends one request and gets back one response. I've purposely built some random lag into the activation procedure at the target. In both activation procedures, I do what one would expect if I see the user-defined message types (I respond to Requests and record Responses). On both sides, I end the conversation in the activation procedure to avoid stale conversation accumulation. This appears to clear all messages from that particular conversation.

---

This is one of the things for which you can use [conversation timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx). The idea is that you augment your workflow by issuing a `BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER` statement after you send your message. Choose a timeout value that is a reasonable amount of time for the message to be processed plus some wiggle room. Then "listen" for the DialogTimer event on the sender side. I can flesh this out a little more with a worked example later, but hopefully this will give you some ideas.

Comment: Yes, I'll need more guidance on this.  I will try to improve the clarity of my question so it's more clear what my end goal is.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. But, as I'm sure you know, setting up the plumbing for service broker can be a little time consuming. I'll tackle it at some point over the weekend.

Comment: I've been studying your design.  It seems to me it's aiming at bouncing messages silently back and forth in the background, while the main interactive connection is doing the initiating.  My main goal is for external application A or B to do an update to table X, and as a result, external applications C,D, and E are awakened from their WAIT_FOR and notified that they need to refresh changes from table X.  The conversation initiator has to be the applications C,D, and E, but the messages need to be initiated on that conversation come from application A or B.

Comment: In the example I've got above, I'm logging an error status in the `ConversationHistory` table once the timeout is detected from the initiator side. The key point is that it's able to detect that state at all. Once that's done, you can process it in any way you feel is appropriate (e.g. "send the message again", "raise an alert to your monitoring service"). But I'm confused by your topology. Specifically, it seems like you're saying "I'm application C and I'm going to start a conversation specifically to wait for change notifications". Are changes guaranteed to come in at a fixed cadence?

Comment: Your sentence with quotes describes exactly what I want to do.  I could set each connection to poll a table for changes, but there might be 0 changes in a day, or there might be hundreds, and there could be 1 connection, or there could be 50, so I want each connection to just sit there idle in a WAIT_FOR until a trigger wakes it up.  I just don't want to leave garbage behind if a connection dies.

Comment: And if the answer is "you shouldn't be doing that in SQL Server", I'll live with that, and find a way to communicate those wakeups over a different channel.  I was just hoping to keep all communication through the database.

Comment: Whelp… *now* I understand what you're looking for. Effectively, you want a heartbeat. Adding onto what I described in the comment above, you'd do something like "I'm app C; give me all my changes" on some sort of cadence (say every 5 minutes). If the far side of that conversation hasn't heard a request in a while (let's say 15 minutes in my example), you want to clean up. Does that sound about right? If so, I'm going to start over (but I do have my plumbing code… which is nice). This is an interesting problem!

Comment: I can write an application which executes a query every 5 minutes.  But what I want is an application that will be notified within seconds of new data being written to a specific table, without having to run a query every few seconds.  The trigger I wrote actually does this, but I want to make sure everything is guaranteed to get cleaned up.

Comment: There has to be some sort of inherent timer here otherwise what you're asking doesn't make sense. Now you could have your application send heartbeat messages on a cadence to the target queue, but that's still some sort of time-based thing. You'd still be consuming messages continually. I can make something work with that.

Comment: I added a new answer (rather than shoehorn this one into what you're looking for). Let me know if you'd like to keep this one around for posterity or delete it. It doesn't matter to me one way or the other.

Comment: You can keep all this, here.  It could be useful to someone in the future, you never know.

Comment: There are a lot of things I don't know. :) Glad the other approach helped!